# Is there a way to check when the media starts streaming and starts playing

Tags: android

I have built an app that streams radio urls. I want to show an alert dialog when the user click on play button and hide the alert dialog when the player starts playing. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there was a callback to when the MediaPlayer is ready to play. I'm not sure what API you're using, but there is usually a listener or callback for such important things.

There is **onBufferingUpdate** and **onPrepared**, see which one works best for you.